# Set CENTOS 6 mysql character sets to UTF8

Tags: mysql, hibernate, utf-8, centos6, my.cnf

I have a website, and I realised when you copy some characters(`*,' " - _`) from specific applications like Microsoft word, into a search box on my website, it returns this error:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

So I went to check out my database and I wanted to see if the database used UTF-8.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, the database is using `latin1` and I wanted to set it to use `utf8`. So firstly, I'm on a `Centos 6.2` server and the file `my.cnf` file resides in `/etc/my.cnf` and the file is as follows under the `[mysqld]`:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
init_connect ='SET NAMES utf8'
character_set_server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci
```

P.S I am not worried about the `[client]` section since it shows that it uses `utf8` under the value of `character_set_client`. 
**The issue:**
Although I've tried to set the server in my `my.cnf` file (and closed the file, shutdown my tomcat and restarted my tomcat). Nothing is changing. And when I run the first query I displayed, it still shows that `character_set_server` is still using `latin1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although restarting my TOMCAT didn't have any effect, I actually had to restart my 'mySql' in order for the changes to take place. So you'd have to stop the main server first (in my case `Stop TOMCAT`) and then restart `mySql` and then `Start TOMCAT` again. After, in your `mySql` if you type: `show VARIABLES like %character%;` you should see your database datatype with `utf-8` and if you type: `show VARIABLES like %collation%` you should also see your database collation data type which should be `utf-8_general_ci`.